# Convert SQL table from Long Data to Wide Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have an SQL table that contains survey data.  Unfortunately, the survey questions are long data instead of wide data (I have a column that has all the question numbers and I need the question numbers to be their own columns).

I have:

```
question_id | question_format_id | response----- | format_type | question
---63-------|------8-------------|--synchronous--|--likert-----|How will you attend class
---64-------|------3-------------|--COVID concern|short answer-|Reason for selection
```

I want:

```
63 ----------------------| 64
8------------------------| 3
synchornous--------------| COVID concern
likert modality----------| short answer
How will you attend class| Reason for selection
```

Is that possible?
The reason is that I'm trying to do reporting on students that select a certain answer for question 63.  However, as soon as I put a filter on the responses for the questions, I no longer see both questions.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: indeed you need unpivot, but unpivoting tecniques might change from one DBMS to another one. So, what's yours? Since `SQL` is just a query language.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `UNPIVOT` clause , and then `PIVOT` clause might be applied such as

```
SELECT [1] AS col1, [2] AS col2
  FROM
  (
   SELECT *
     FROM ( SELECT CAST(question_id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS question_id, 
                   CAST(question_format_id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS question_format_id, 
                   response,format_type,question,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY question_id) AS rn
              FROM [tab] ) t  
  UNPIVOT  
     (val FOR col IN   
        (question_id,question_format_id,response,format_type,question)  
     ) AS upt 
   ) ut
 PIVOT 
 (
  MAX(val) FOR rn IN ([1],[2]) 
 ) AS pt
```

in order to transpose the values in a vertical manner.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3f2e2d8b652153ab3eaf68f22afb5e66)</kbd>